# Call of non-procedure in function definition?

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I found a short introduction to Scheme online, and I'm having a bit of trouble with this function:

```
(define (title-style str)
  (let loop ((lc #\space) (i 0) (c (string-ref str 0)))
    ((if (char=? lc #\space)
       (string-set! str i (char-upcase c)))
     (if (= (- (string-length str) 1) i)
       str
       (loop c (+ i 1) (string-ref str (+ i 1)))))))

(display "star wars iv: a new hope")
(display (title-style "star wars iv: a new hope"))
```

When I try calling it, I get this:

```
Error: call of non-procedure: #<unspecified>

    Call history:

    title-style.scm:6: loop
    ...
    title-style.scm:1: g6          <--
```

That error comes from Chicken Scheme, I am also getting the same results in Chez Scheme.

It converts a string to title case, and from the error messages I got earlier, it does: `call of non-procedure: "Star Wars Iv: A New Hope"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand what you intend to do, but that's not the right way to structure a conditional expression in Scheme. Also, right before the first `if` there's a misplaced opening parentheses (which is the one causing the reported error), and you have to advance the recursion in all cases. This should work for non-empty strings:

```
(define (title-style str)
  (let loop ((lc #\space) (i 0) (c (string-ref str 0)))
    (cond ((= (- (string-length str) 1) i)
           str)
          ((char=? lc #\space)
           (string-set! str i (char-upcase c))
           (loop c (+ i 1) (string-ref str (+ i 1))))
          (else 
           (loop c (+ i 1) (string-ref str (+ i 1)))))))
```

But still, it's not the recommended way to write a solution in Scheme, you're mutating the input string along the way, which is discouraged, and you're thinking in terms of indexes. Besides, you're imposing an extra restriction on your input: that the strings must be mutable, and not all Scheme dialects support this *by default*.

A functional tail-recursive style is preferred, where we create a new string as output, leaving the original input untouched and leveraging the rich library of list procedures available in the language; this is what I mean:

```
(define (title-style str)
  (let loop ((lc #\space) (lst (string->list str)) (acc '()))
    (cond ((null? lst)
           (list->string (reverse acc)))
          ((char=? lc #\space)
           (loop (car lst) (cdr lst) (cons (char-upcase (car lst)) acc)))
          (else
           (loop (car lst) (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) acc))))))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(title-style "star wars iv: a new hope")
=> "Star Wars Iv: A New Hope"
```

Comment: An added upside of using the `string->list` and `list->string` approach (compared to `string-ref`) is that on R7RS, `string-ref` (and `string-set!`) is allowed to be O(n) (for implementations where strings are represented internally as UTF-8, and so each character can occupy a different number of bytes).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still trying to wrap my head around how cons cells work, this is helping a lot.

Comment: Probably no implementation supports this by default when the argument evaluates to a string constant. Chicken, Racket, Gambit, Ikarus all displays undefined behavior and often without signaling an error like the report recommends.